# Sqoop incremental

Tags: hdfs, sqoop, sqoop2

Is it possible to have incremental load by Sqoop for teradata on the basic of load time whose datatype is `timestamp(6)`? How it handles the format while loading in hdfs:

> sql exxeption:- expecting something '(' and ').

Answer (score 0):

So you have one column which is loadtime [type timestamp(6)].
While pulling the data to HDFS you have to create a 3 step process. Also have to create partition in hdfs end.
I prefer this way because you don’t to mess with older data.
But you could use [`--incremental`](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.2/SqoopUserGuide.html#_incremental_imports) option in sqoop.

1. Fetch the max of loadtime present in the hdfs. If that is 1st time pass a default value something like `0000-00-00 00:00:00.000000`
2. While pulling data via sqoop add one condition pass that `WHERE loadtime > ${max_of_loadtime_in_hdfs}`. You will be passing `max_of_loadtime_in_hdfs` as an argument.
3. Save the data in a newer partition

Now timestamp format would be different for teradata and hive.
It's better to cast to string while saving it to hive.

So while checking the loadtime with your hive loadtime(string type) you have to [cast back](https://docs.teradata.com/reader/kmuOwjp1zEYg98JsB8fu_A/AAtEdpLjV2nIKveJL~sdWw#:~:text=Teradata%20Conversion%20Syntax&text=a%20character%20expression%20to%20be%20cast%20to%20a%20TIMESTAMP%20type.,-data_attribute&text=a%20single%20digit%20representing%20the%20number%20of%20significant%20digits%20in,The%20default%20precision%20is%206.) to timestamp(6).
So in your condition in sqoop end will be (which ever works for you):

- `WHERE loadtime > CAST(${max_of_loadtime_in_hdfs} AS TIMESTAMP(6))`
- `WHERE loadtime > TO_TIMESTAMP(${max_of_loadtime_in_hdfs}, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss.ff6')`

**max_of_loadtime_in_hdfs** will be something like this 
`2020-12-31 23:59:59.999999`

So in your final sqoop query:

```sql
SELECT
    column_A,
    column_B,
    ...
    column_N,
    to_char(loadtime, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss.ff6') loadtime
FROM teradata_table
WHERE loadtime > TO_TIMESTAMP(${max_of_loadtime_in_hdfs}, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss.ff6') 
AND $CONDITIONS --this is for sqoop don’t remove this
```

hive table definition:

```sql
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE teratable_in_hive (
    column_A <column_A_datatype>,
    column_B <column_B_datatype>,
    ...
    column_N <column_N_datatype>,
    loadtime string
)
PARTITIONED BY (pull_seq_no <type can be int or string>)
STORED AS <file_format TEXTFILE / PARQUET>
LOCATION 'hdfs:///<some-path>/teratable_in_hive'
```